# Problem with Jquery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Jquery UI dialog form does not wait till I give the inputs. I am expecting the functionality to be like Javascript prompt. I have requirement like if filename is empty open a dialog such that user can fill the details and proceed with the saving but execution does not wait till I give the inputs.

```
//code steps

if(testcasefilename==""){

open a dialog, enter details, get the details on click of OK button, assign it to filename
}

//use the filename and proceed to saving.

saveForm(filename){

}

//code
```

Edit: I am using jquery UI modal dialog confirmation http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation with a drop down and text input so that user can select dropdown, provide text value. Our requirements does not allow us to use jconifrm or javascript prompt. Please let me know is there a way to achieve my requirement using Jquery UI dialog

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what it is that you are asking... are you saying that it is going into the IF statement when it shouldn't yet?  If so, how is testcasefilename setup?

Comment: When I click on save button, if filename is empty it goes into if statement, opens a dialog so that user can provide values. On click of OK set the filename, come out of if loop and proceed with saving using filename. But in my case, dialog gets opened, comes out of if loop even without providing details and remaining code is getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the jQuery [alert](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/) plug-in.

For example:

```
if(testcasefilename==""){
  jConfirm('Enter a file name', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
    saveForm(r);
});
}
```

Comment: Does this fulfill the OP's requirement of halting script execution until an input is made? I don't think so

Comment: Completely halting script execution on the page is something I try an avoid. Using the alert plug-in and using the callback functionality should give a nicer experience to the user.